# Hide a div if the fiels is empty

Tags: php, functions, custom-field

I have a problem to hide a div when the input of a custom field is empty.
This is the code I am using, it's fine when the field is not empty. But when the fireld empty, the div will show.

The field that displays the content is postintro2, the div I want to hide when empty is

```
<div class="single2-intro">
```

The complete codes is:

```
<?php { $postintro2 = get_post_meta ($post->ID, 'postintro2', $single = true);
if($postintro2 !== '') 
echo '<div class="single2-intro">'.$postintro2.'</div>';                            
} ?>
```

Thanks for any helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$postintro2 = get_post_meta ($post->ID, 'postintro2', true);

if ( ! empty( $postintro2 ) ) {
     echo '<div class="single2-intro">'.$postintro2.'</div>';                            
}
```

From the codex: [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)

Comment: Unfortunately, the div still appear when the field is empty.

Comment: It may look empty, but not be. Try `var_dump( $postintro2 );` before the `if` statement.

Comment: Thank you. It's work.